# LaTeX - Writing Text In A Matrix

Tags: r, matrices, formatting

I am trying to write text into a matrix to describe what an element at a particular row and column represents. The following is as far as I got ( after a few hours! ):

```
\begin{equation*}
P_{m,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{description 1 - some text} & p_{1,2} \\
p_{2,1} & \text{description 2 - some more text}  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

The text does not wrap and its size is too big relative to the rows and columns that do not have a description. Is it possible to write wrapped text in a matrix using LaTeX ( I am using Markdown in RStudio )? - if it is - what are the LaTeX commands?

Comment: do not use the \text and it looks  way better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the text in a `\parbox` and specify both the text width and size.  Also, I show a TABstack alternative in which the row baselineskip `22pt` and column gap `3pt` are easily specified.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
P_{m,n} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\parbox{.6in}{\raggedright\tiny description 1 - some text} & p_{1,2} \\
p_{2,1} & \parbox{.6in}{\raggedright\tiny description 2 - some more text}  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\setstackgap{L}{22pt}
\setstacktabbedgap{3pt}
P_{m,n} = 
\parenMatrixstack{
\parbox{.6in}{\raggedright\tiny description 1 - some text} & p_{1,2} \\
p_{2,1} & \parbox{.6in}{\raggedright\tiny description 2 - some more text}
}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Rmarkdown anyways stating formulars canb be easyer using $ .. $ or $$...$$.

```
$$P_{m,n} = \begin{pmatrix} description1 & p_{2,1}\\p_{1,2}\ & description2\end{pmatrix}$$
```

The upper one is using your Latex code without /text

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use a combination of `tabular` and `\left` `\right` commands as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
$$
\left(
\begin{tabular}{m{2cm}<{\centering}m{2cm}<{\centering}}
description 1 - some text & $x$\\
$y$ & description 2 - some text
\end{tabular}
\right)
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not very elegant, but maybe it is close to what you desire. Morover, you can adapt the width of the columns and not givin an absolute length.